# Отсутствует подключение к интернету в созданной сети докер

Tags: mysql, сеть, docker

При установке докера по инструкции с этого сайта: [Установка Docker на Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-ubuntu-18-04-1-ru)

И настройки сети докера:

> docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet123

Отсутствует подключение к интернету, и я не могу подключиться к удаленному серверу базы данных MySQL. Я получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Странно то, что в дефолтной сети докера подключение работает, но не из одной созданной сети не удается подключиться. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Host в конфиге - IP, URL? Если первое - достижим ли хост из новой сети? Если второе - что с DNS в новой сети?

Comment: Host  в конфиге - IP. Недостижим, был бы достижим, подключился бы к базе. Но он достижим с моей виртуальной машины вне докера.

Comment: Значит, что-то с маршрутизацией - или у самого докера, или в настройках узла.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решить удалось изменением --subnet=172.19.0.0/16.